# How to load WMT_MS_Capabilities using Javascript

Tags: javascript, wms

I would like to load and parse an `WMT_MS_Capabilities` using Javascript. I have unsuccessfully tried severaly ways. I am trying with this [file](http://www.geo.euskadi.net/arcgis/services/S91B_AGS_WMS/MapServer/WMSServer?VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS) but I always get this error:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: file:///home/frowing/Projects/XMLParsing/testXML.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 10" data: no]
```

I hope someone can throw some light on this because I have no idea where to go next.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks helpful - http://www.koders.com/javascript/fid6B33B196FE110C97EBEF2C3A4FD212CA27BA823F.aspx?s=wms#L3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you'll need a proxy unless that is the site you are running your JavaScript from. See http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost for more details.

Comment: If I had debugged with Chrome instead of Firefox, I would have known right away from the error it gives you. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The WMT_MS_Capabilities file seems ok. I have validated it twice using the on-line XML validation services http://www.validome.org/xml/ and http://www.xmlvalidation.com/, and in both cases no error was found.

Thus, the error must be somewhere in *file:///home/frowing/Projects/XMLParsing/testXML.js*.